# onMessageReceived is Never Called when FCM Notification Received, API 19 above

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

**Update**
onMessageReceived called in API 19 but not on 23 and 24.
**Update**

I am sending FCM notifications from a server, I can receive notifications but onMessageReceived is not called(foreground, background), even with data messages. This is the code I'm using.

```
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

import uk.co.socktchat.socketchat.MainActivity;

public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

 private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";

    /**
     * Called when message is received.
     *
     * @param remoteMessage Object representing the message received from Firebase Cloud Messaging.
     */
    // [START receive_message]
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        // [START_EXCLUDE]
        // There are two types of messages data messages and notification messages. Data messages are handled
        // here in onMessageReceived whether the app is in the foreground or background. Data messages are the type
        // traditionally used with GCM. Notification messages are only received here in onMessageReceived when the app
        // is in the foreground. When the app is in the background an automatically generated notification is displayed.
        // When the user taps on the notification they are returned to the app. Messages containing both notification
        // and data payloads are treated as notification messages. The Firebase console always sends notification
        // messages. For more see: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options
        // [END_EXCLUDE]

        // TODO(developer): Handle FCM messages here.
        // Not getting messages here? See why this may be: 
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

        // Check if message contains a data payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());

            if (/* Check if data needs to be processed by long running job */ true) {
                // For long-running tasks (10 seconds or more) use Firebase Job Dispatcher.
                scheduleJob();
            } else {
                // Handle message within 10 seconds
                handleNow();
            }

        }

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }

        // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
        // message, here is where that should be initiated. See sendNotification method below.
    }
    // [END receive_message]

    /**
     * Schedule a job using FirebaseJobDispatcher.
     */
    private void scheduleJob() {
        // [START dispatch_job]

        // [END dispatch_job]
    }

    /**
     * Handle time allotted to BroadcastReceivers.
     */
    private void handleNow() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Short lived task is done.");
    }

    /**
     * Create and show a simple notification containing the received FCM message.
     *
     * @param messageBody FCM message body received.
     */
    private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);


    }
}
```

My Manifest file

```
<service
    android:name=".fcm.MyFirebaseMessagingService"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
<!-- [END firebase_service] -->
<!-- [START firebase_iid_service] -->
<service
    android:name=".fcm.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

json im posting from server

```
{
    "data": {
    "title": "5x1",
    "body": "15:10"
  },
    "to" : "d6IJZlXAUZ4:APA91bF8kB_jBn_N93otIdRFsu89ZDhrFsL--i0I4TmS-LO_h3QQ79lu6VlTQe0poNpuUni7N45_jw2XMli",
    "priority" : "high",
    "content_available" : true



 }
```

I don't see anything wrong, I tried different versions of Android, thinking android version could be any reason, but didn't seem the find any problem. Any ideas?  Thank you.

Comment: please post notification json

Comment: edited the post

Comment: Please check your SERVER_API_KEY

Comment: also google-services.json file

Comment: you mean in google-services.json?

Comment: have u know server api key

Comment: i know the server key, i can receive the notifications btw

Comment: you are sending notification from one device to another device i think

Comment: so where you using that key

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167317/discussion-between-naveen-tamrakar-and-anil-m).

Comment: in headers when im posting to https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact `onMessageReceived` is being called the whole time, it is just that Logcat didn't show any messages, weird enough it happened only with devices of API 19 above, on a device with API 19 Logcat is showing the messages, I can't explain why this happened but my problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Check if message contains a notification payload.

```
if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Notification Payload: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
            //handleNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }
```

Check if message contains a data payload.

```
if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0){
   Log.e(TAG, "Data Payload: " + remoteMessage.getData().toString());
   handleNotification(remoteMessage.getData());
}
```

Comment: can u post Json That Yor are sending from server to fcm

Answer (score 0):

As per FCM document

> Notification messages contain a predefined set of user-visible keys.
>   Data messages, by contrast, contain only your user-defined custom
>   key-value pairs. Notification messages can contain an optional data
>   payload. Maximum payload for both message types is 4KB, except when
>   sending messages from the Firebase console, which enforces a 1024
>   character limit.

check that your message size is within limit.

Comment: i don't think the payload is more than 1kb